# Angular Material design cant get value from text field

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a text field that I am trying to read the value from when it is changed. After I modify the field (by removing characters) I keep getting undefined, although the event does fire as expected. What am I doing wrong here?

Result of the code below:

```
changed: {"isTrusted":true} undefined
```

View:

```
....
<ng-container matColumnDef="email">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Email </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let e">
        <mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
            <input matInput placeholder="no email" (change)="emailUpdated($event)" [value]="e.email" [(ngModel)]="e.email">
        </mat-form-field>
    </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
....
```

in my component:

```
emailUpdated(event) {
    console.log('changed: '+JSON.stringify(event)+' '+event.email);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the updated value in the handler of the `change` event with `event.target.value`:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="e.email" (change)="emailUpdated($event)" ... >
```

```
emailUpdated(event) {
  console.log("New email", event.target.value);
}
```

You could also simply use `e.email`, since it is bound to the input element with `[(ngModel)]`:

```
emailUpdated() {
  console.log("New email", this.e.email);
}
```

---

As an alternative, if you want to be notified as the value is being modified (on each key stroke), handle the `ngModelChange` event:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="e.email" (ngModelChange)="emailUpdated($event)" ... >
```

In that case, the `$event` parameter is the updated value:

```
emailUpdated(value) {
  console.log("New email", value);
}
```

---

Note: you don't need to bind `[value]` since you are using two way data binding.